# Optimize Animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate

I want to build an "Slide" animation using jQuery. I have 2 divs `nav` and `page`.
The sequence it should be this example

http://jsfiddle.net/qhXvN/

My problem is that this solution is not optimal in IE7 and IE8. Do you have a idea for better performance?

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to force this animation on those old browser, you could gracefully degrade to some other (more simple) effect, e.g. a simple fadeout/fadein.